# print format has unused arguments

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I have the following:

```
data = [['Harry', 25, 5, 1.00],['Sally', 30, 7, .50]]

print('{%s}  \n'.format(data[0][0]))
```

Spyder ide says I have missing arguments at positions 0 when I run the code I get keyError: '%s'  I can't for life of me spot the problem

type(data[0][0]) comes back as string

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up `printf`-like formatting with [Python format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)? Python's format string syntax doesn't use `%` placeholders, only curly-braces (`{}`). It looks like you want `'{}  \n'.format(...)`. Or better yet, use an f-string: `f"{data[0][0]}  \n"`.